# Nested Table Loop Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

---

I am having some trouble writing some nested `HTML Tables` from my Laravel Collection.

### My Model

```
public static function offers($userId)
{
    return DB::table('users_vehicles')
    ->join('dealer_offers', 'users_vehicles.id', '=', 'dealer_offers.vehicle_id')
      ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
      ->select('users_vehicles.*', 'dealer_offers.*');
}
```

### My Controller

```
public function dash()
{

    $userCars  = UserVehicles::offers(Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('customer.dash', compact('userCars'));
}
```

### My Collection Results

[image: a busy cat]

### In My View blade Template

```
@foreach( $userCars->chunk(1) as $userCarChunk)
    <div id="no-more-tables">
        <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <caption>Offers for My Mazda 326 </caption>
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th class="numeric">DEALER RATING</th> 
                    <th class="numeric">AMOUNT </th>
                    <th class="numeric"> 3 DAYS To Accept </th>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
            @foreach( $userCarChunk as $car)
                <tr> 
                    <td data-title="First Name">
                        <div class="rating">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" title="5 stars"> 5
                            </label>

                        </div>
                    </td> 
                    <td data-title="Last Name"> 55 000 </td>
                    <td data-title="Username">
                        <a href="{{ route('customer.eval.show', 1) }}">Accept</a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody> 
        </table>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

### Front-End View

[image: a busy cat]

### Question

How can I create a nested HTML Table for all the user vehicles, so that I can write the vehicle name and all the offers for that particular vehicle?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Can you share your table structure. From first glance it seems that you can solve your problem by using eloquent relationships instead of using `DB::table('users_vehicles')` (which is a definite sign that something is off with your code).

Comment: [link to view Full Model](https://ibb.co/iZ1Yo6)

Comment: Table structure. Not ORM models. I'm going to assume that you have tables `user_info <--> user <--> user_vehicles <--> vehicle_offers <--> dealer`  in that order of relationships? If that's the case then you should do `$iteratee = UserVehicles::with("vehicle_offers")->whereHas("vehicle_offers")->where("user_id",auth()->id())` and for each vehicle you print the vehicle and then a table of relevant offers. No need to have a static anything anywhere.

Comment: [You mean This](https://ibb.co/khum86)

Also, I will try your suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
<div id="no-more-tables">
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <caption>Offers for My Mazda 326 </caption>
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th class="numeric">DEALER RATING</th> 
                <th class="numeric">AMOUNT </th>
                <th class="numeric"> 3 DAYS To Accept </th>
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            @foreach( $userCars->chunk(1) as $userCarChunk)
                @foreach( $userCarChunk as $car)
                    <tr> 
                        <td data-title="First Name">
                            <div class="rating">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" title="5 stars"> 5
                                </label>

                            </div>
                        </td> 
                        <td data-title="Last Name"> 55 000 </td>
                        <td data-title="Username">
                            <a href="{{ route('customer.eval.show', 1) }}">Accept</a>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try to do that. But and it did not work. Because I want to output the vehicle name on the `Table Caption` :: `<caption>Offers for My {{  }} </caption>`

Comment: Did you have relationships between the models ??

Comment: See [this link](https://ibb.co/iZ1Yo6) as well as this one [model link](https://ibb.co/khum86)

Comment: Let us continue in chat [discussion !](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157497/nested-table-loop-laravel-5-4)

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

#### My Model `UserVehicles.php`

```
public function offers() {
    return $this->hasMany(DealerOffers::class, 'vehicle_id');
}
```

#### My Controller `CustomerController.php`

```
$offersToCustomer = UserVehicles::with('offers')->get();
```

#### Dashboard `Blade template`

```
@foreach( $offersToCustomer as $offer)
    <div id="no-more-tables_">
        <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <caption>Offers for My :: <b style="color: #00BFF0"> {{ $offer->vehicle_make }} {{ $offer->vehicle_model }}  </b> </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="numeric">DEALER RATING</th>
                    <th class="numeric">AMOUNT REQUESTED </th>
                    <th class="numeric">AMOUNT OFFERED </th>
                    <th class="numeric"> Expires :: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($offer->offer_expiry)->format('d-m-Y') }} </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach( $offer->offers as $subOffer)
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="DEALER RATING">
                            <input id="rating" name="rating" class="rating rating-loading" value="3" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="1"  />
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="AMOUNT REQUESTED">R  {{ number_format($offer->vehicle_amount_asked, 2, '.', ' ') }} </td>
                        <td data-title="AMOUNT OFFERED">R  {{ number_format($subOffer->offer_amount, 2, '.', ' ') }} </td>
                        <td data-title="ACTIONS">
                            <button data-offer_id="{{ $offer->id }} " data-vehicle_id="{{ $subOffer->vehicle_id }}"
                                            class="btn btn-xs btn-success accept-offer">Accept</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

#### Output

[image: Output For The Front End]